# Showing that $x^r$ is strictly rising if $r>0$ and strictly decreasing if $r<0$ and finding the inversefunction,$r\in\mathbb{Q}, x>0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have problems to Show that the function $x\mapsto x^r$ where $x^r:=\sqrt[q]{x^p}$ and $r=\frac{p}{q}$ is strictly decreasing if $r<0$ and also I don't know how I can proof that the function $x\mapsto x^{\frac{1}{r}}$ is the inverse function.

What I have done so far is proving the case when $r>0$. If $r$ is natural then one can Show it with induction easily if $r=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then if $b>a$ then also $b^p>a^p$ and then also $\sqrt[q]{b^p}>\sqrt[q]{a^p}$ which means $b^r>a^r$

Please give me the solution for my other Questions or Maybe a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $$f(x)=x^r$$ so $$f'(x)=rx^{r-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the Reply I understand that if the first derivative is positive then the function is rising and if it is negative it is decreasing however the book I am reading has not introducced derivatives yet.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comment to the answer by [Dr. Sonnhard Graubner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/175066/dr-sonnhard-graubner) that you haven't had derivatives introduced yet. Here is what I believe is a more basic approach that I trust doesn't use anything you haven't yet covered. Consider

$$f(x) = x^r \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Next, consider any $2$ values $x_1 \gt x_2 \gt 0$. Then

$$\frac{f(x_1)}{f(x_2)} = \frac{x_1^r}{x_2^r} = \left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)^r \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Let $x_3 = \frac{x_1}{x_2} \gt 1$. Note that the natural logarithm is a strictly increasing function, with $\ln(y) \lt 0$ for $y \lt 1$, $\ln(y) = 0$ for $y = 1$, and $\ln(y) > 0$ for $y > 1$. Next,

$$\ln\left(x_3^r \right) = r\ln(x_3) \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

As $x_3 \gt 1$, this means that $\ln(x_3) \gt 0$. Thus, if $r \gt 0$, then $x_3^r \gt 1$, so you can show using \eqref{eq2} (I will leave the details for you to fill in) that $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function. Similarly, if $r \lt 0$, then $f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function.